# PHP LDAP admin doesn't create users on the OS

Tags: php, ldap, phpldapadmin

I am using [phpldapadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net) on Ubuntu.
I can create user and groups on the web interface, but then I don't see new users created on the OS.

Is the web interface linked with the internal os user database? Or should I repeat twice the operations:

1. On phpldapadmin to create users
2. On the OS to create users?

Doing twice the job seems strange to me.

Comment: phpldapadmin creates the users in an LDAP, not on the local system. When your local system authenticates via LDAP that's enough. But to be of some help it would be great to describe what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how ldap is working, and would like to have my users connecting to ubuntu through ldap. Would ldap create homedir for each user when an app is using ldap to connect someone ? Would then ldap service create users on the os ?